# Where can I find scanned documents I can use to train my OCR machine learning app?

Tags: research-process

I am looking for resources that can let me access scanned documents and memos to train my OCR application.  I have some client documents but need more for product development.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try an academics desk : there is usually a stack of copied papers on one corner...

Comment: Perhaps openlibrary.org

Comment: biodiversity library - internet archive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go the other way round: Find digital documents, render them as images (e.g. print and scan them), then apply OCR and compare the result with the original document.

Comment: I think also the typical deviations from the printed documents could be added relative easily (minor rotations, spots, shades, a little bit of random noise, etc - these are probably very easy in an OCR project)

Comment: Good ideas, good ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried working with Project Gutenberg? Apart from pioneering work in offering free eBooks, they manage an army of volunteers to help with the processing of these gems.

They have a library of OCR images that sounds just up your alley. Check out their [FAQ](https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Volunteers%27_FAQ#V.52._What_role_does_proofing_play_in_Project_Gutenberg.3F) on proofing. Most people head of the [Distributed Proofreaders](https://www.pgdp.net/c/) site.

Good luck!